# Почему гугл-поиск вставляется на сайт таким способом?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var cx = '243523444203045243455:ds143bvd4se';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Ну то есть насколько я понимаю можно было бы сделать так:

```
<script src='https://cse.google.com/cse.js?243523444203045243455:ds143bvd4se=243523444203045243455:ds143bvd4se' async></script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно для того что бы гарантировать что скрипт подгрузится асинхронно. `gcse.async = true;` и никакой внешний скрипт до отрабатывания текущего не смог повлиять на эти атрибуты.

Comment: Чем атрибут `<script async>` не гарантирует этого?

Comment: может они так сделали просто для удобства? ну чтобы пользователь не думая просто вставил код в одно место и всё